# Get a reference to knex client in feathers app

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

How can I get a reference to `knexClient` that the `app` uses, when I have a `test.js` file that exports multiple functions? For instance, test.js could be used to perform scheduled operations to the database and it's not part of a service.

```
    module.exports = {

      const knex = app.get('knexClient');

      doThings: function (params) {  
       //I NEED KNEX HERE
       return something;
      },

      doThings2: function () {
        return somethingElse
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a generated application `src/app.js` (see [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/src/app.js)) exports the `app` object:

```
const app = require('./app');
const knex = app.get('knexClient');

module.exports = {
  doThings: function (params) {  
    //I NEED KNEX HERE
    return something;
  },

  doThings2: function () {
    return somethingElse
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. By doing so I get an error for the `app.get` saying `TypeError: app.get is not a function`

Comment: Is this a generated application? Is the file you are importing (`src/app.js`) setting `module.exports = app;`?

Comment: I've generated the app using `feathers-cli` and inside myprojecy/src/app.js at the end of the file I have `module.exports = app;`. Calling services from browser work and also using knex from a service works too.

Comment: I'm not seeing how it is possible that `app.get` is undefined then (unless `module.exports` is overwritten somewhere later).